# Need equivalent CSS Selectors of an XPATH expression

Tags: html, css, xpath, css-selectors

I have an html code as below :

```
 <div id="select_a_boundary" class="dataset_select2">Homes name</div>
```

I wrote a xpath expression for the same:

```
 //div[@id = 'select_a_boundary' and @class = 'dataset_select2']
```

What will be the equivalent CSS Selectors for the same?

Comment: @Mr. Alien: This is XPath, so the `//` should not be removed as it has significant meaning.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry for that, I thought the code was commented, thanks for the re-edit

Comment: @Mr. Alien: No problem, it's a syntax highlighting issue so that confuses a lot of other people too.

Comment: @BoltClock yea :) but now on I will try to avoid such edits where am not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all if you are using `id`, you don't require to use class, secondly if you are willing yo select an element with an id `select_a_boundary` you can use

```
#select_a_boundary {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s6JLU/2/)

> Note: Am not selecting the element which has that id and that class as
>   here, id is sufficient as it has to be unique, if you are using the id
>   for multiple elements than it's invalid

---

As per your comment

```
div[id=select_a_boundary][class=dataset_select2] {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo X-Path Equivalent**](http://jsfiddle.net/s6JLU/1/)

Or an easier one (Credits: [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack))

```
#select_a_boundary.dataset_select2 {
    color: red;
}
```

> Note: Still I would recommend you to use `#select_a_boundary` is more
>   than enough

Comment: So is this `#select_a_boundary.dataset_select2` and `div[id=select_a_boundary][class=dataset_select2]` are `and` equivalent?

Comment: @Priti just use any of 1

Comment: That I understood.. I am just telling it is the way to do `and` operation in CSS selectors.. :)

Comment: @Priti say you can break it like this `div having  [id=select_a_boundary] and [class=dataset_select2]` ;)

Comment: I used this one - `div[id=select_a_boundary][class=dataset_select2]`. I wrote a script using `xpath`,but my boss told me to do it using `CSS` :(.. I was not sure.. So I asked help here.. :) thanks for helping..

Comment: @Priti no issues, if you want, `#select_a_boundary { /* Styles here */ }` will help you too :)

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of your expression in CSS is this:

```css
#select_a_boundary.dataset_select2 {
    /* whatever */
}
```

Because identifiers in a single document should be unique, you can even narrow it down to:

```css
#select_a_boundary {
    /* whatever */
}
```

One important thing to realize is that although XPath and CSS selectors have many similarities, they're two different things.

For instance, there's no XPath equivalent of `:active` or `:hover` for instance. Properly matching by class names is also more cumbersome with XPath.

On the other hand, CSS can't match things like "all paragraphs with an anchor child" which is trivial in XPath using `//p[a]`.

Comment: That's true. There are a lot of things you can do with XPath that can't be done with a selector (and perhaps a handful of things you can do with a selector but not XPath).

Comment: @BoltClock So this won't work in xpath? If no than I would like to remove this from my answer

Comment: @Mr. Alien: What do you mean?

Comment: @BoltClock Oh nothing, I just read your comment properly, this works too... but really `#id` is more than sufficient

Comment: @Jack: That's why I said "perhaps" :)

Comment: @BoltClock Actually, you're right, the pseudo selectors is something you can't do with XPath, e.g. `:active`, `:hover`, etc.

Comment: @Jack: There you go :)